# Order array of type float in descendent order java

Tags: java

I am a newbie in Java. I need order a array of type float in order descendent, but my code seems not working

```
package java1;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
public class Orden{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float []nums={23.6,35,5,4,4,3,10.9,2,45,56};
        Float[]floatArray=new Float[nums.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            floatArray[i]=nums[i];
        }
        Arrays.sort(floatArray,Collections.reverseOrder());
        for (int i = 0; i < floatArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("num:"+floatArray[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: _but my code seems not working_ What did your extensive debugging reveal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and it worked fine for me after declaring 23.6 and 10.9 as float.

```
float []nums={23.6f,35,5,4,4,3,10.9f,2,45,56};
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is to pass the float numbers to the float array. ie to specify `f` to the values of the numbers.

```
    float[] nums = {23.6f, 35f, 5f, 4f, 4f, 3f, 10.9f, 2f, 45f, 56f};
```

Try this.. this works.

```
    float[] nums = {23.6f, 35f, 5f, 4f, 4f, 3f, 10.9f, 2f, 45f, 56f};
    Float floatArray[] = new Float[nums.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        floatArray[i] = nums[i];
    }
    Arrays.sort(floatArray, Collections.reverseOrder());
    for (int i = 0; i < floatArray.length; i++) {
       System.out.println("num:" + floatArray[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should append f to each constant number with a decimal point to make Java compiler read it like a float.

If you don't, it will read it as a double.

You choices are:

1. Append f to each number with a decimal point.
2. Use "Double" instead of "Float".